# EF Core code first migration to Azure Web Service

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, continuous-delivery

I have some experience in EF 6 database first. But this is my first time attempting EF Core as well as code first migration.

I have read/watch some tutorials. Most of the tutorials use local database, commands such as `add-migration` or `update-database` are issued via `Package Manager Console` - which work great, if everything is done locally.

However in real life environment, I have to set up a Continuous delivery using Azure Web Service and Azure SQL database as the backend, and this is where I'm stuck. How do I set up the environment so that these commands are run and the database is being updated automatically every time I deploy the code?

Comment: Isn't it the same as if the SQL database was on-prem? Just use the correct connection string and it should work.

Comment: Most of the tutorials taught us how to apply the database changes locally, and manually, but I just couldn't figure out how to automate the database update.